# NodeJS: Send chunks in multiples of 256 KB size

Tags: node.js, google-api, byte

I want to perform a resumable upload with Google Drive REST API: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resumable-upload
I must send chunks in multiples of 256 KB size until the end of the upload.

Imagine I have a chunk of 300KB * n size, how can I split it to get a multiple of 256KB in NodeJS so I can keep the rest for the next chunk ?

Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: Can you show the code you have at the moment?

Comment: If my understanding for your question is correct, at the resumable upload of Drive API, the last chunk is not required to be the multiple of 256KB.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but if you are using stream then use **highWaterMark**
which is use to limit the buffer.